# Jena QueryParseException Encountered "regex"

Tags: regex, debugging, exception, sparql, jena

I have built this SPARQL Query:

```
String query_splInfo = 
    "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>"+"\n"+
    "SELECT ?name"+"\n"+
    "WHERE {?x foaf:name ?name . " +
    "FILTER regex(?name, \"Studienprogrammleitung Informatik\")}";
```

Jena returns an error message:

> Failed: com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " "regex" "regex "" at line 4, column 73.
>   Was expecting one of:
>       "graph" ...
>       "optional" ...
>       "filter" ...
>       "{" ...
>       "}" ...
>       ";" ...
>       "," ...
>       "." ...

Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem query? Jena is complaining about line 4, but you only have 3 lines in this (two \n).

Answer (score 0):

```
"PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>"+"\n"+
"SELECT ?name"+"\n"+
"WHERE {?x foaf:name ?name . "+"\n"+
"FILTER regex(?name, \"Studienprogrammleitung Informatik\")}";
```